# Child widget to expand within parent height (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get Container 3 (blue) to expand to cover the below remaining area that ends at the bottom level of the yellow box. The yellow box has a variable height, which will depend on the children heights, and can be anything.

I've tried to wrap Container 3 with an Expanded, but I get the following error

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

the code

```dart
    return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
    
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange[50],
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
    
                              width: 50,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    child: Text("1"),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    child: Text("2"),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    child: Text("3"),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.amberAccent,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Text("---"),
                                  Text("Variable"),
                                  Text("Height"),
                                  Text("---"),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
```

[image: Current Result]

[image: Desired Result]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you're not providing any sort of height to your `Row()`, therefore whenever you wrap that container in `Expanded()` it doesn.t have any boundations to how much it can **expand to**.

What you can do in this situation is provide a `SizedBox()` with a specified height to your `Row()` and then apply `Expanded()` to your container, something like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(

      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox( //Add this SizedBox()
        height: 100,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                color: Colors.red,
                width: 50,
                child: const Text("1"),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                color: Colors.green,
                width: 50,
                child: const Text("2"),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    width: 50,
                    child: const Text("3"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.amberAccent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: const [
                    Text("---"),
                    Text("Variable"),
                    Text("Height"),
                    Text("---"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),)
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hi Risheek, thanks you for your answer, however, that solves part of the problem. It doest expand the blue container (3), but then it does not allow the yellow container to grow. The whole problem here is that the height of the yellow container is unknown, and it should grow if its content requires. because of this reason I can't fix the size of the row. The idea is that if the yellow container grows, the blue container should grow as well.

Comment: See the thing is, Expanded() doesn't work like that, Expanded will try to take all the place in that Scaffold(), this is why Container() is used as it wraps itself to the size of its contents. But then again your components are not that big to get your desired result, which means you either need to give variable height to the SizedBox() which I've added or add all the elements of the Column() below such that Expanded() for Container(3) will get some height constraint.

Comment: Looks like I need to have a fixed height for the yellow box. This becomes a limitation to my requirement, however I can't see another solution. Anyway, thanks Risheek.